# Simple javascript doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have almost no experience in javascript and I'm trying to make my website load a bit of html code from a google drive file. This works fine in every browser except for in safari. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#leaderboard").load("https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU"); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @AbuOmar `$(function(){})` appear equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){})` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: ah thanks didn't know that before :)

Comment: The error that Safari throws is 'Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers'. Perhaps look into Access-Control-Allow-Headers in relation to Google Drive.

Comment: Do you open the link to your page with https, or with normal http?

Comment: I open the link with https

Comment: then you can change the link to jquery to be without http, like this:
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
does that work?

Comment: @AbuOmar I was thinking you meant instead: `$("#leaderboard").load("//www.googledrive.com/host/0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU");`

Comment: @rwacarter Are you OP or what? It is quite confusing, i guess you have tested it on your side but... If not then OP should answer if there is any error in console.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't show up on safari

Comment: @Wolff No, I think the problem with jquery link, opening http inside https page is a problem

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes sorry, should have been more clear. I recreated the problem in safari and checked the error console.

Comment: yeah I got the same error as @rwacarter

Answer (score 0):

This Security issue is know as [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

> In computing, the same-origin policy is an important concept in the
>   web application security model. The policy permits scripts running on
>   pages originating from the same site – a combination of scheme,
>   hostname, and port number[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) – to access each other's DOM with no
>   specific restrictions, but prevents access to DOM on different
>   sites.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) The same-origin policy also applies to XMLHttpRequests
>   unless the server provides an Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS)
>   header. Notably, WebSockets are not subject to the same-origin policy.
>
> This mechanism bears a particular significance for modern web
>   applications that extensively depend on HTTP cookies to maintain
>   authenticated user sessions, as servers act based on the HTTP cookie
>   information to reveal sensitive information or take state-changing
>   actions. A strict separation between content provided by unrelated
>   sites must be maintained on the client side to prevent the loss of
>   data confidentiality or integrity.

jQuery.load function can't get content from another domains in some browsers due to this security issue. and the same thing is applied to XMLHttpRequests function.

```
$('#leaderboard').load('http://google.com'); //May work and may not work!
```

But you can use Jquery.ajax or Jquery.get function instead.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        // your code
    }
});
// Works with $.get too!
```

Comment: This got rid of the errors, but it strangly still doesn't end up working in safari.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.protocol 
             + "//www.googledrive.com/host/0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU",
        cache: false,
        context: $("#leaderboard"),
        dataType: "html"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      $(this).html(data)
    }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown)
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qvc27vmq/

See also http://browsershots.org/

Comment: Didn't work on any browsers sadly, I got this error  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU?_=1421525077437. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
leaderboard.html:27 DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU?_=1421525077437'.

Comment: Tested from a local web page ? , loaded from local `filesystem` ? i.e., see `file://` (`file:`) `protocol` ? Tried http://jsfiddle.net/qvc27vmq/ ?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.I only tried it offline before. I just tested it online but it has the same issues as before. It works on all browsers I tried except for safari.

Comment: [Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU?_=1421528423576. Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (leaderboard.html, line 0)

Comment: Again with the same error. [Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7VK-PTvOFWwRnVzUUlRX1BQZUU?_=1421528810720. Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (leaderboard.html, line 0)